# Limit sum value after 5 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which contain some values, If I want to add all these values, I need sum up to 100 no more than this. I want to make cell un-clickable disabled after sum=100. More over I want number of clicks up to maximum 5. My fiddel 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdRYMQ

```
<div class="container">
<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">10</td>
            <td class="combat">15</td>
            <td class="combat">30</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">50</td>
            <td class="combat">20</td>
            <td class="combat">50</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

  <div class="sum">sum:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share some code for us to help you with your request.

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your codepen that you have tried to do this yourself?

Comment: Do you want to count up to a hundred per column or in total?

Comment: Know you are a beginner, first try to make full HTML and try to attempt with some  jquery, one getting clear visual  we can help u soon

Comment: @JanAndersen in total . I want my result in div "sum" which should be upto 100 .. and disable after total 100 or after 5 clicks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```js
let sum = 0;
let clicks = 0;
$sum = $(".sum");
$clicks = $("#clicks");

$(".combat").on("click", function(){
  if(clicks >= 5) return;
  clicks += 1;
  $clicks.text(`clicks:${clicks}`);
  const $this = $(this);
  const val = parseInt($this.text());
  
  if(sum + val <= 100){
    sum += val;
    $sum.text(`sum:${sum}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<table>
   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">10</td>
            <td class="combat">15</td>
            <td class="combat">30</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">50</td>
            <td class="combat">20</td>
            <td class="combat">50</td>
            
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
  
  <div class="sum">sum:</div>
  <div id="clicks">clicks:0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple exercise to iterate over the cells, get their numbers, add it and apply a class to the cell if the total is over 100.Not entirely sure of what you want clickable etc - since td's are not normally a clicked element, so I simply applied a class and styling to show the cells that are over the 100 limit- form there you can do stuff as you want.

Note that you do NOT need jquery for such a simple process - learn the newer document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll for such things.

As in the comments - please try to show the working code you have tried.

```js
var total = 0;
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.combat');

cells.forEach(function(cell){
 var cellNum = parseInt(cell.innerText);
 total +=cellNum;
 if(total > 100) { cell.classList.add('over100')}
 })
 
 document.querySelector('.sum').innerHTML = 'sum: ' + total;
```

```css
td.over100 { color: red}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">10</td>
            <td class="combat">15</td>
            <td class="combat">30</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">50</td>
            <td class="combat">20</td>
            <td class="combat">50</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

  <div class="sum">sum:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou brother for your kind reply,Actually I am a beginner in field.I will follow your suggestions .